# disable ng-bootstrap date and time for previous dates in angular7

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, ng-bootstrap

## html

```
     <ngb-datepicker (select)="onDateSelect($event)" [(ngModel)]="datePickerModel"></ngb-datepicker>

 <ngb-timepicker [meridian]="meridian" [(ngModel)]="time" class="fromTimePick">
                </ngb-timepicker>
```

How to disable the calendar dates for past days i.e. disabling days before today and time before now (ie disable past time before current time with respect to current date) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ngb-datepicker, you can set the `minDate` input binding to disable past dates:

```
<ngb-datepicker (select)="onDateSelect($event)" [(ngModel)]="datePickerModel"[minDate]="todayDate">
```

And on your component.ts, you set `todayDate` as today.

```
const current = new Date();
this.todayDate = {
  year: current.getFullYear(),
  month: current.getMonth() + 1,
  day: current.getDate()
};
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdbjdu?file=app/datepicker-basic.html)

As for the timepicker, you cannot explicitly disable the hours/minutes picker using the ng-boostrap API, but what I can suggest is to write your custom validation outside the timepicker to prevent the user from submitting a form whereby the time is invalid?